# Why all records are not being fetched from one database to another database though Database Process in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A database process, that runs every day at an interval of 3 hours, is supposed to insert all records (based on specific conditions) from one database table to another, with truncate load. However, if the source table contains 1500 records, only 20 records are getting inserted into the child table.

I have tried running the database processes manually. But in this case, the full load occurs, i.e., all the records are successfully inserted from parent to child table.

However, when the process runs as per schedule, incomplete transfer takes place.

Below is the database process for the load of data:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM source_DB.dbo.BA_Invoice_Tb
WHERE Invoice_Date > '2016-01-01'
  AND Update_Date Between DateAdd(MINUTE, -720, GETDATE()) and DateAdd(MINUTE, -0, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Is your Schedule happening once a day and at mid night ?

Comment: @Ven It is scheduled to run 8 times per day at an interval of 3 hours: 00:00, 03:00, 00:06 and so on.

Comment: I can only think of `script difference` with automation or `server time`